# Can anyone tell me which font is used in this logo?

Tags: font-identification

[image: The Whisky World logo]

I’ve tried so many different websites, but none of them gave me the exact result.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a font called **[Veneer Two](https://creativemarket.com/YellowDesignStudio/8013-Veneer-Font-Family?u=Slidesmash)**:

[image]

Veneer font family is available for purchase on Creative Market.

Comment: Yup, Veneer Two does look really similar, although a little bit more worn out than the font in the logo, but this should do. Thanks!!

Comment: Veneer Two has two different capital letters for upper and lowercase input. Try changing the sample text on the website to WHISKYwhisky, and you will see what I mean...